# Jquery Keyword Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery for searching record from the list displayed. Record is searched by entering a single word or complete word from the table where record is displayed. Now the problem is in the record table i have a column of id. When the users enters the id number the the record is searched accordingly. I want to allow the user to search the record from specified columns i-e: title, author etc not id/pages.

Here is the jquery code:

```
$(function () {
    $( '#table' ).searchable({
        striped: true,
        oddRow: { 'background-color': '#f5f5f5' },
        evenRow: { 'background-color': '#fff' },
        searchType: 'fuzzy'
    });

    $( '#searchable-container' ).searchable({
        searchField: '#container-search',
        selector: '.row',
        childSelector: '.col-xs-4',
        show: function( elem ) {
            elem.slideDown(100);
        },
        hide: function( elem ) {
            elem.slideUp( 100 );
        }
        })
    });
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">


        <div class="row" style="padding-top:20px;">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4" style="padding-left: 130px; padding-top: 30px;">
                <input type="search" id="search" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search by Book Title/Author/Publisher">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <table class="table" id="table">
                    <thead style="background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #6D6C6C">

                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th id="book" class="b">Book Title</th>
                            <th id="book" class="b">Author</th>
                            <th id="book" class="b">Publisher</th>
                            <th>Pages</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php

                        $x=0;

                        foreach ($result as $row) {?>

                        <tr>
                            <td ><?php echo $x = $x+1; ?></td>
                            <td id="book" class="b"><?php echo $row->TITLE; ?></td>
                            <td id="book" class="b"><?php echo $row->AUTHOR; ?></td>
                            <td id="book" class="b"><?php echo $row->PUBLISHER; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row->PAGES; ?></td>
                            <td><a href="<?php echo $row->PATH; ?>" style="text-decoration:none;" target="_blank"><input id="button" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="View" name="submit"></a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php } ?>

                    </tbody>

                </table>
                <hr>
            </div>
                <div id="page" style="float: left; width: 100%; text-align: center">

                </div>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: if you knew which column the user was looking for you can do this using the `nth-child()` selector and search the values of that child for each row. So if author was the second column of the table you could get it saying `nth-child(2)`

Comment: I believe you have 6 different elements all sharing an id of "book"...

Comment: @metsales
actually i am new to the jquery. I am using an opensource code, can you please elaborate how to use this nth-child() combination in the code, if I only want things to get searched by author name, publisher, editor?

Comment: @Mudi first... on the other persons point... you never have more than 1 element on a page with the same `id`. Anyway, `nth-child` is a CSS selector so you would say `tr td:nth-child(2)` to select the second column.

Comment: @Mudi something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/xTjaZ/